# Scroll issue on asp modal popup extender

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender

Im using asp:modalpopup extender for a registration form in asp c# application, for every postback the modal popup closes, so im re opening the modal popup on each postback. my modal popup contains more elements of big lengthy form.

After i reopen the functionalities and entered values are not changed, but the display view is always top on each postback show. For example user enters middle entries and post back occurs means after it does post back event and opens modal popup it shows the top of modal popup again, so user needs to scroll down every time unnecessarily.

What i want is i needs to open my modal popup with auto scrolled to middle.

Thanks alot in advance .

Answer (score 0):

try to set in the source of your aspx page

MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/MyMaster.Master"
CodeBehind="Mypage.aspx.vb" Inherits="Myproject.Testing" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

Or you can use an updatepanel, will prevent popup extender to close after posting back.